# How to style posts selecting a CSS post_class (added through custom_fields?)?

Tags: custom-field, css, post-class

Here is what I tried and couldn't reach it. Maybe I need a whole different approach?

1) I created a custom field in a post, called `post-class` and inserted the value `cita-flow800000` (weird class name means: citations flow structure using the `#800000` as the main color, for those who might be curious)

2) I called the new custom_value in my `content-single.php` in front of the `post_class` function, and inserted the variable inside the `post_class` function, like this:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('class-1 class-2' . $custom_variable); ?>> <?php $custom_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_class'); ?>
```

3) I selected the class in my `style.css`:

```
.cita-flow800000 p { font-size: 30px; }
```

As an example, but nothing happens.

Could it be done, to style posts differently and accordingly to post classes? Creating different classes for different post structures and selecting/creating them in the post meta custom fields and in the `style.css` sheet?

PS - I tried changing the variable inside the post_class function into `$custom_values`, thinking that `$custom_variable` could be a typo from the post that shared the recipe, but it still didn't work. All functions seem to be calling all variables correctly, so why doesn't it work?

Anyone who can point me in the direction where I could learn and apply this?

Comment: Can you check what classes are there in the article? Is `cita-flow800000` included in the class?

Comment: I'm searching on how to verify if the article includes the class. No luck. Do you know how?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the primary problem in your code is the `$custom_values` is set *after* you try to use it (and you need to use the same variable name). Otherwise, it doesn't have a value when it's in `post_class()`. In fact, I'm surprised you're not getting an error. That variable needs to get the value *before* the call to `post_class`.

```
<?php $custom_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_class'); ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'class-1 class-2' . $custom_values ); ?>>
```

In the above snippet, you also need to account for the fact that `get_post_meta()` returns an `array` by default. (This means the above code snippet still probably wouldn't work.)

So instead of all that, the best practice is to use the [`post_class` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters) (which would also mean you get this class if the post shows up on an archive page too.

To use the filter, you'd use a snippet like this (untested), probably in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'wpse182657_post_class', 10, 2 );
function wpse182657_post_class( $classes, $post_id ) {
    // get the meta
    // true assumes you only use one value per this key on any single post
    // if false, you'd have to loop through the array with a foreach loop
    $post_class = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_class', true );

    // add $post_class variable to $classes array
    $classes[] = esc_attr( $post_class );

    // run along now, $classes
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Great explanation. I'm learning with all the details. I still don't get why it didn't work for me, as well as the other recipes I found, both through editing the content-single.php and through a functions.php filter. Anyway, I found one that worked out. Added it in an answer below.
Thanks for your input.

Comment: @mrwweb Any way of doing this using the value from a color picker on the edit category screen and using inline styles rather than CSS added to style.css

Comment: @mrwweb Any idea on how you would use these custom field values with wp_add_inline_style

Answer (score 0):

It's working, finaly. The link to the source and the code which worked out are below.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/64124/69825 (Check for the Update #1 edit in the answer)
It was through editing the content-single.php rather than through a filter in the functions.php file. I tried 2 or 3 recipes of each. I couldn't understand why they didn't work out.

```
<?php $my_class = get_post_meta($post->ID, "your_meta_name") ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $my_class ); ?>>
```

It creates a variable $my_class and adds it to the post_class function. The value is determined in the custom fields of the post meta data.

The variable is created before it is called in the function, as mrwweb advised in the previous answer here above.