# Add custom CSS class to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, css

I created custom post type called 'song' in the installation. I am running on a theme called  `fabulous`

When I viewed the author archive page with custom posts, the post are not correctly displayed (errors in CSS configurations). I use the foloowing code to display custom posts in the author page.

```
function custom_post_author_archive($query) {
    if ($query->is_author)
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'song' );
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_author_archive' );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_author_archive');
```

But the archive page with normal posts are displayed (when the above function is not used) correctly. When I checked the codes I noticed that several CSS classes are missing from the `<article>` tag. I added the missing CSS classes using the developer mode of the browser and the *songs* displayed correctly.

The missing CSS classes were `song-entry` `masonry-entry` `col-` `loop-entry` `col` `clr` `span_1_of_3`

I used [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) to create the custom post type **song**.

My question is, how can I add those missing CSS classes to the `<article>` tag so that the posts are displayed correctly?

Note: I tried [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/64115/70765) question and couldn't understand what exactly to do.

Comment: Have a look at [`post_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class). Check if the theme using it (every good theme should). If so then you can use `post_class` filter to add appropriate classes to the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`post_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class). Check if the theme using it (every good theme should). If so then you can use `post_class` filter to add appropriate classes to the container.

**Here is an example how you can use that filter**

```
add_filter('post_class', function($classes){

    if(!is_singular('song'))
        return $classes;

    $additional_classes = array('song-entry', 'masonry-entry', 'col-', 'loop-entry', 'col', 'clr', 'span_1_of_3');

    $classes = $classes + $additional_classes;
    return $classes;

});
```

Hope it helps. *Code not tested*