# Return the_content() with custom div class for a subset of posts

Tags: theme-development, the-content

Is it possible to have `the_content()` function return the post content in a `div` with a custom CSS class (i.e. something other than `the-content`)?

I have a unique post I'm trying to lay out that requires styling of the main content block that is different from virtually all other posts on the site. I'd like to create a custom class just for this subset of posts.

Comment: Does this answer solve your question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/258351/110572?

Comment: On a quick look, I think the post_class filter should do exactly what I need. I'll try it later today. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in multiple different ways. For example:

### 1. Using `the_content` filter hook:

Use [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter hook to wrap the output of `the_content()` function call with your required `div`.

You may try the following CODE in your theme's `functions.php` file or in a custom plugin:

```php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_specific_the_content' );
function wpse_specific_the_content( $content ) {
    // logic to identify unique posts
    // for example, using specific post ID
    $unique_ids = array (12, 14, 21);
    // current post ID
    $id = get_the_id();
    if( in_array( $id, $unique_ids ) ) {
        return '<div class="unique-posts">' . $content . '</div>';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

### 2. Use `post_class` filter hook:

You don't actually need to wrap `the_content()` in additional `div`. Instead, you may use the [`post_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_class/) filter hook.

This way, you will be able to assign unique CSS classes to different posts and pages that needs them and style them based on those CSS classes.

For example:

```php
add_filter( 'post_class', 'wpse_filter_post_class' );
function wpse_filter_post_class( $class ) {
    $unique_ids = array (12, 14, 21);
    $id = get_the_id();
    if( in_array( $id, $unique_ids ) ) {
        // add these custom CSS classes to matching posts
        $add = array( 'custom-posts', 'some-class' );
        $class = array_merge( $add, $class );
    }
    return $class;
}
```

Now target this class the way you need:

```css
.custom-posts {
    background-color: gold;
}
.custom-posts .entry-content {
    background-color: red;
}
```

### 3. Use `body_class` filter hook:

If you need more generic control over the entire page design (compared to what `post_class` will provide), then you may modify `<body>` class using the [`body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/) filter hook, the same `post_class` filter hook is show above.

Like this:

```php
add_filter( 'body_class', 'wpse_filter_body_class' );
function wpse_filter_body_class( $class ) {
    // this check is needed for body_class hook,
    // because the current page may not be a single post at all.
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $unique_ids = array (12, 14, 21);
        $id = get_the_id();
        if( in_array( $id, $unique_ids ) ) {
            $add = array( 'custom-body' );
            $class = array_merge( $add, $class );
        }   
    }
    return $class;
}
```

Now you can use the following CSS to target custom post page:

```css
body.custom-body .any-inner-content-class {
    color: blue;
}
```

Since this custom class is added to the `<body>` tag, this way you'll be able to target any element within the page.